# View with button and list fragment under it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to create view with button and fragemtn with list under this button. The problem is that the list starts from top of button not from bottom and it's look like this:

[image]

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.BluetoothActivity">

    <Button
            android:text="@string/scan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/BluetoothScanButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/BluetoothDevicesFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.tatara.taffico.DeviceListFragment"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BluetoothScanButton"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Could anyone help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add  **`android:layout_height="0dp"`** ***fragment*** section.

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/BluetoothDevicesFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
```

[**`ConstraintLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

> You can also define one dimension of a widget as a ratio of the other
>   one. In order to do that, you need to have at least one constrained
>   dimension be set to 0dp (i.e., MATCH_CONSTRAINT).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/BluetoothDevicesFragment"` in the Button.

Comment: It's working for list but button margin top stoped working